# Помогите с решением задачи (нужно точки заменить на звездочки)

Tags: python

Сама задача:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код этой задачи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что я на 30 строке , где j == 3 (тройку я поставил от руки(подогнал под решение)) чтобы печатались центральные вертикальная и горизонтальная строки из звездочек.
Прошу Вас помочь, подсказать, **объяснить** что нужно поставить в последнем блоке кода чтобы печатались центральные вертикальная и горизонтальные строки из звездочек(*) вместо точек(.)

Comment: Пока вам не накидали минусов, то дайте задачу и текст программы не картинками, а текстом. Используйте символ ` 3 раза перед и после кода, чтобы его выделить.

Comment: А `numpy` и `random` в решении такой простой задачи - это чтобы врагов запутать?

Comment: нет, numpy - для того чтобы каждая строка массива печаталась с новой строки, random для того чтобы сделать задачу универсальной(чтобы можно было подставлять разные значения и она работала)

Answer (score 2):

На скиншоте многабуков, ниасилил.
Но, видимо, решение выглядит как-то так:

```
n = int(input())
matrix = [['.']*n for _ in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][i] = matrix[i][n-i-1] = matrix[i][n//2] = '*'
matrix[n//2] = ['*']*n
print(*map(' '.join, matrix), sep='\n')
```

#### Подробности

Конструкция вида `['.']*n` создаёт список длиной `n` состоящий из элементов `'.'`. *(Т.е., к примеру, запись `[7]*4` породит список `[7,7,7,7]`)* Таким образом генерируется ряд матрицы.

Чтобы заполнить матрицу такими рядами, всё действо просто повторяется в цикле `[... for _ in range(n)]`. Данная запись эквивалентна обычному циклу с вызовом `append(...)`:

```
for _ in range(n):
    matrix.append(['.']*n)
```

Дальше заполняем матрицу звёздочками:

```
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][i]     = '*'  # главная диагональ
    matrix[i][n-i-1] = '*'  # побочная диагональ
    matrix[i][n//2]  = '*'  # средний столбец
```

Если идет присваивание одного и того же значения нескольким переменным, то можно не городить кучу однотипных строк, а просто записать в виде однострочной конструкции как, например, `a = b = c = d = 5` *(т.е. всем перечисленным переменным будет присвоено значение 5)*.

Ну и в конце просто присваиваем средней строке матрицы список из одних звёздочек *`matrix[n//2] = ['*']*n`*.

#### Вывод на экран

Тут немного tricky...

Символ `*` говорит Питону, что элементы списка надо раскидать по аргументам. Т.е., к примеру, строка `print(*[1,2,3])` сделает поэлементную постановку списка в аргументы, и, по сути, она как бы превратится в `print(1,2,3)`.

Разделитель по умолчанию является пробел, но аргументом `sep='\n'` меняется на перевод строки. Таким образом, если просто позвать `print(*matrix, sep='\n')`, каждая строка матрицы пойдёт как отдельный аргумент в команду `print()`, и будет напечатана этой командой с новой строки *(так как аргументы печатаются через разделитель, а он был заменён на перевод строки `\n`)*.

Но строки матрицы всё ещё списки, и будут напечатаны как списки, если ничего не предпринимать. Поэтому просто клеим списки через пробел *(при помощи функции `join()`)*. Для этого задействуем функцию `map()` которая идёт по списку и для каждого элемента вызывает функцию, которую указали первым аргументом. Т.е., например, `list(map(str, [1,2,3]))` преобразует каждое число в строку и вернёт список `['1', '2', '3']`.

Сам `join()` работает очень просто - он собирает (клеит) элементы списка в строку используя строку, от которой его вызвали, как разделитель. Например, `'<>'.join([1,2,3])` вернёт строку `'1<>2<>3'`. В нашем случае в качестве разделителя используется строка содержащая пробел.

Короче, `print(*map(' '.join, matrix), sep='\n')` преобразует каждый ряд матрицы из списка в строку через пробел при помощи `map()` через `' '.join()`; из-за того, что указана `*` - распихивает эти ряды по отдельным аргументам команды `print()`, которая выводит ряды построчно, потому как указан разделитель `\n`.

Comment: Если есть возможность могли бы вы расписать более подробно код, т.к. я еще не умею писать в одну строку

Comment: @Karaban Расписал подробности. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ !

Comment: Никак не пойму как это применить в моем коде

Comment: @Karaban Это, собственно, замена всему вашему коду.

Comment: Это я понял. Но меня интересует что мне нужно заменить в моем коде чтобы он заработал

Comment: @Karaban Не могу сказать, ибо ваш код в виде скриншота невозможно исполнить.